# ¿Si duplico un array se modifican cada uno con el mismo contenido?

Tags: php, java, php7

Quiero saber **¿por qué Java interpreta los siguientes arrays de esta manera?**

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
int[] b = a;
System.out.println("a: " + Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println("b: " + Arrays.toString(b));

b[0] = 10;
System.out.println("\nCAMBIO");
System.out.println("a: " + Arrays.toString(a));
System.out.println("b: " + Arrays.toString(b));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mientras que en PHP no pasa esto.**

```
$a = array(1,2,3);
$b = $a;
echo "a: "; print_r($a); echo "<br>";
echo "b: "; print_r($b);

$b[0] = 10;
echo "<br><br>CAMBIO<br>";
echo "a: "; print_r($a); echo "<br>";
echo "b: "; print_r($b);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor, cambia las imágenes por el texto del código. Así se podrá usar para hacer pruebas. Cuando haces en Java `int [] b=a;` no creas un objeto nuevo, si no que en `b` creas una *referencia*  de `a`, por eso, todo lo que le ocurre a `a`, le ocurre también a `b`. En PHP si pasas el objeto por referencia ocurriría lo mismo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso ocurre porque en Java, al hacer esto:

```
    int [] b=a;
```

No estás creando realmente un objeto nuevo, sino que lo que haces es crear en `b` una **referencia** al mismo objeto `a`, por tanto, todo lo que cambies en `a`, cambiará también en `b`.

Si ejecutas este código, verás por pantalla algo como esto:

```
    int [] a={1,2,3};
    int [] b=a;
    int [] c={1,2,3};
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    System.out.println(b.toString());
    System.out.println(c.toString());
```

**Salida:**

```
[I@15db9742   -- a
[I@15db9742   -- b
[I@6d06d69c   -- c
```

`a` y `b` tienen asignada la misma posición en la memoria.

Si ejecutas este código verás que el comportamiento es distinto, porque al usar `int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);`, lo que se crea en `b` es **un nuevo objeto**, con el mismo contenido de `a`. Ahí, `b` no apunta ya a `a` ni ocupan la misma posición en la memoria, son dos instancias distintas y lo que afecte a `b` no afectará jamás a `a`.

Si observas los identificadores de los objetos, son distintos ahora:

```
    System.out.println(a.toString());
    System.out.println(b.toString());
```

**Salida:**

```
[I@15db9742   --a
[I@6d06d69c   --b
```

Dado que se copiaron los valores de `a` en `b`, inicialmente tendrán los mismos datos:

```
    int [] a={1,2,3};
    int[] b = Arrays.copyOf(a, a.length);
    System.out.println("ANTES:\n");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

**Salida:**

```
ANTES:

[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Pero si haces cambios en cualquiera de ellos, no afectará al otro:

```
    a[0]=-8;
    b[0]=-4;
    System.out.println("\n\nDESPUÉS:\n");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
```

**Salida:**

```
DESPUÉS:

[-8, 2, 3]
[-4, 2, 3]
```

---

En PHP los valores no son usados como referencia (por defecto), sino como valor. Pero puedes usar también referencias, para eso se usa la `&`.

Veamos un comportamiento similar al de Java en PHP:

```
$a=array(1,2,3);
$b=&$a; #Al usar & pasamos por referencia, no por valor
print_r($a);
print_r($b);

$b[0]=10;
$a[1]=-5;

print_r($a);
print_r($b);
```

**Salida:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => -5
    [2] => 3
)
Array
(
    [0] => 10
    [1] => -5
    [2] => 3
)
```

¿Por qué? Porque aquí: `$b=&$a;` `$a` es pasado como ***referencia***.  Y todo lo que ocurra en cualquiera de los dos afectará al otro.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!!! 
Aclaré varias dudas.